# Absolute path for .class file?

Tags: grails, classloader

I want to find the absolute path of a class file from the class loader.
So when I do this:

```
println("Absolute path for class MyClassName: ${(new MyClassName()).getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()}")
```

I am getting this output:

*Absolute path for class MyClassName: `/home/codehx/git/myAppName/target/work/scriptCache/`*

while I was expecting to get:

*Absolute path for class path:   `/home/codehx/git/myAppName/target/classes/com/app/myAppName`*

I am doing this at bootstrap so may be the above code is trying to give the path for the `bootstrap.class` file.

So I checked both dirs (`/home/codehx/git/myAppName/target/work/scriptCache/` and `/home/codehx/git/myAppName/target/classes/com/app/myAppName`) and  I found:

`BootStrap.class` on `/home/codehx/git/myAppName/target/classes/com/app/myAppName`

`_GrailsBootstrap_groovy.class` on  `/home/codehx/git/myAppName/target/classes/com/app/myAppName`

What is the difference between the two and for what purpose is the *scriptCache* dir used in grails?

thanks.

Comment: Instead if you explain what you are trying to achieve with absolute path to class, why you need to know the exact path of the class, some one may provide a better solution.

This should give you the path in file system

new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());

Comment: Looking at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3494 it appears that `/path/to/app/target/work/scriptCache/` is used for caching Gant scripts. Where are you trying to execute that code?